Loop through each unique date in array based on criteria
In Sheet 1, I have a flat-file format of data, including dates.
In Sheet 2, in Cell A1, I have a date of 01/01/2019 and in cell A2 a date of 31/12/2019.
In VBA I need to be able to pick out the unique dates from Sheet 1 which are within the date criteria specified in A1/A2 in Sheet 2 and put them into Sheet 3, incrementing one row for each unique date.
Sheet 1 data structure is like follows:
    A            B
1   02/01/2019   Chromium
2   02/02/2019   Chromium
3   02/06/2019   Chromium
4   02/09/2019   Chromium
5   03/03/2020   Chromium
6   05/06/2020   Chromium
7   02/01/2019   Cadmium
8   10/10/2019   Cadmium
9   20/11/2019   Cadmium

In the example dataset above, there are nine rows with dates in and eight unique dates overall, but only six of them fall within the date criteria specified above.
I'll be incorporating this into another loop within the wider VBA code.
I'm wondering if I need to use a dictionary?

Yes, using Dictionary to get the unique value.
Please share the details of the code you tried and describe the issue you are encountering.

Use the technique shown  here to return the unique array (ie remove the Count wrapper) and loop that

Short, easy and fast solution is
Option Explicit

Sub GetUniqueDatesBetween()
  Dim a, b, al&, i&, j&, lb&, ub&, pv&
  a = Application.Sort(Sheet1.[A1].CurrentRegion.Columns(1).Value2)
  lb = Sheet2.[A1].Value2: ub = Sheet2.[A2].Value2
  j = 0: al = UBound(a, 1): ReDim b(al, 0)
  For i = 1 To al
    If a(i, 1) >= lb Then Exit For
  Next
  pv = a(i, 1) - 1
  For i = i To al
    If a(i, 1) > ub Then Exit For
    If a(i, 1) > pv Then
      b(j, 0) = a(i, 1)
      pv = a(i, 1)
      j = j + 1
    End If
  Next
  Sheet3.[A1].Resize(j, 1) = b
End Sub

UPD
If you need to incorporate "this into another loop within the wider VBA code", you can use the next function:
Public Type ArrL
  Length As Long
  Values As Variant
End Type

Function LoopThroughOmitDuplicates(rng As Range, lb&, ub&) As ArrL
  Dim a, b, al&, i&, j&, pv&, ob&
  a = rng.Value2: al = UBound(a, 1): ob = al + 1
  b = Application.SortBy(Application.Sequence(al), a)
  For i = 1 To al
    If a(b(i, 1), 1) >= lb Then Exit For
    b(i, 1) = ob
  Next
  j = 0: pv = a(b(i, 1), 1) - 1
  For i = i To al
    If a(b(i, 1), 1) > ub Then Exit For
    If a(b(i, 1), 1) > pv Then
      pv = a(b(i, 1), 1): j = j + 1
    Else
      b(i, 1) = ob
    End If
  Next
  For i = i To al: b(i, 1) = ob: Next
  Dim res As ArrL
  With res
    .Length = j: .Values = Application.Sort(b)
  End With
  LoopThroughOmitDuplicates = res
End Function

The test call:
Sub test()
  Dim res As ArrL
  res = LoopThroughOmitDuplicates(Sheet1.[A1].CurrentRegion.Columns(1), Sheet2.[A1].Value2, Sheet2.[A2].Value2)
  Sheet3.[A1].Resize(res.Length, 1) = res.Values
End Sub


This function produces the array with indexes of unique dates while other entries are replaced by the over bound index. The j variable gives the number of unique entries. You can loop through this array till j.
This is very efficient algorithm which is faster than usage of a dictionary in most cases.
Testing
I conducted three tests on 150000 data table. Execution times (in seconds) are provided in last two columns:

The left column is for the sort-based algorithm (my code).
The right column is for the dictionary-based algorithm (by CDP1802).




Formula
Data sample
ll
ul
Lower bound
Upper bound
Unique values
With sort
With dictionary




(1)
03.03.2020
26.01.1900
07.12.2150
01.01.2000
31.12.2050
14898
0,1
0,71


(1)
02.06.2019
26.01.1919
07.12.2120
01.01.2019
31.12.2020
580
0,09
0,04


(2)
HAUI26299
01.01.2018
31.12.2022
C
W
115354
0,28
40,51



Formulas:
(1)=RANDARRAY(150000;1;ll;ul;TRUE)
(2)=MAKEARRAY(150000;1;LAMBDA(r;c;CONCAT(CHAR(RANDARRAY(4;1;65;90;TRUE)))))
  &RANDARRAY(150000;1;ll;ul;TRUE)


Tell me if you need to keep the source order.

Thanks, this works in the form of the example, but as you point out it sorts the entire dataset by date, which is not ideal (sometimes the dataset is ~150,000 rows and is typically not sorted by date to make it easier to interrogate. Can it be easily adapted to work without sorting the dataset by date first?

Please pay attention what this solution doesn't sort the dataset on its place. The question is do you need to enlist the unique dates in the order of appearance in the source dataset? If yes, it seems you need not the dates itself but more related information like the more cells or at least the row number.

Depending on your needs, some options can be provided: 1) mark first unique dates; 2) enumerate unique dates while duplicated dates take the same order number; 3) group the output dates by the value of the column B or else.

Check for update please.

The final answer is: No, you don't need to use a dictionary.

How is it going?

Sub GetUniqDates()

    Dim dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date, dt As Date
    Dim arColA, dict, colUniq As Collection
    Dim i As Long, lastrow As Long
    Dim t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set colUniq = New Collection
    
    dtSTart = "01/01/2019" 'Sheet2.Range("A1")
    dtEnd = "31/12/2019"  'Sheet2.Range("A2")
    
    With Sheet1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        arColA = .Range("A1:A" & lastrow)
        For i = 1 To lastrow
             dt = arColA(i, 1)
             If dt >= dtStart And dt <= dtEnd Then
                 If Not dict.exists(dt) Then
                     dict.Add dt, i
                     colUniq.Add i, CStr(i)
                 End If
             End If
        Next
    End With
   
    ' results to Sheet3
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 1 To colUniq.Count
        Sheet3.Cells(i, 1) = arColA(colUniq(i), 1)
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    MsgBox colUniq.Count & " unique dates from " & lastrow, _ 
           vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.00 secs")

End Sub

